# How to get a list of unique elements from particular column in multiple csv files

Tags: shell, unix

hello I have same column name in different  csv files. I want to make a unique(Duplicate value might exist in different multiple CSV files) list of that particular column value and make  list 
as an imaginary example

```
CODE.    DEF    REG.      VALUE
BBS1    Bbs1    reg 7   Heart
ASAP2   Asap2   reg 5   Heart
SPATA22 Spata22 reg 1   Heart
MYLK4   Mylk4   reg 1   Heart
ATP8A1  Atp8a1  reg 5   Heart
```

I want to get list of  unique element from code column .my csv filenaming are same pattern

> 2020-02-9_to_2020-03-05Testcase.csv

please help and guide me

Comment: Could you please do mention how the expected output should look alike in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I can't provide an answer with the info you gave, but you should have a look at the `sort` command (e.g. `sort -u -k4` will sort on column `REG`)

Comment: my idea was building 2 lists from those column value  intersect those lists and keep common values in  a csv file  with column name common values

Comment: Are you trying to do lookup ?  for unique value , if its a CSV(comma delimited file) 

cut -d',' -f1  |  sort |  uniq

Answer (score 0):

```
cat *.csv|awk '{print $"YourColumnNumber"}'|sort -u
```

for example, to get unique value of column 1 from multiple .csv files:`cat *.csv|awk '{print $1}'|sort -u`